# Why is this occuring? (MV missing operand when trying to make sh file executable)

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to make a script (*isorespin.sh*) executable, but everytime I type in the 1st command it says *no such file or directory* or some sort of missing operand, what's happening?

```
sudo mv isorespin.sh /usr/local/bin
```

(After this supposdely works I have to type in:)

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/isorespin.sh
```

Comment: The isorespin.sh file is located in my downloads, if that's helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to either give the mv command the full path to the file, or change your default directory to ~/Downloads before you issue the command you used.

```
sudo mv ~/Downloads/isorespin.sh /usr/local/bin
```

or

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo mv  isorespin.sh /usr/local/bin
```